# Why my copy Variable change the originale value variable In node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, sequelize.js

I don't know why when I change a variable that's a copy of an another var  , both are changed? that doesn't make any sense for me ?

Can you please explain me why ? it's my first time that I face this reaction in node js , I know this in C or C++ when using Pointers  but in node js I don't know why !

```
function getByType(where) {
    var object = {
        topMarque: null,
        posModel: null,
    };
    var countPer = "titre";
    var copywhere = where;
    if (where.categorie == "voiture") {
        countPer = "marqueNom";
        copywhere.marqueId = {
            [Op.ne]: null
        }
    } else {
        console.log("------------------------------------------");
        console.log(where)
        console.log("------------------------------------------");
        copywhere.titre = (where.titre) ? where.titre : {
            [Op.ne]: null
        }
        console.log("******************************************");
        console.log(where)
        console.log("******************************************");
    }
    return db.stats.findAll({
        attributes: [countPer, [db.sequelize.fn('COUNT', db.sequelize.col(countPer)), 'total']],
        group: [countPer],
        limit: 5,
        where: copywhere,
        order: [
            [db.sequelize.fn('COUNT', db.sequelize.col(countPer)), 'DESC'],
        ],
    }).then(function(count) {
        object.topMarque = count;
        return db.stats.findAll({
            attributes: ['pos', [db.sequelize.fn('COUNT', db.sequelize.col('pos')), 'total']],
            group: ['pos'],
            where: where
        }).then(function(countPosCu) {
            object.posModel = countPosCu;
            return Promise.resolve(object);
        });
    }).catch(error => {
        return Promise.resolve(object);
    })
}
```

In the first log i have this :

```
------------------------------------------
{ categorie: 'moto' }
------------------------------------------
```

In the seconde log I have this :

```
******************************************
{ categorie: 'moto', titre: { [Symbol(ne)]: null } }
******************************************
```

Comment: Because you didn't copy anything, you reference the same symbol. Same way as in C or C++: if you have the reference of an object, if you change that object, anything with the same reference will see those changes. If you want a new object then you need to clone it (and beware deep vs. shallow clones, also the same as C or C++).

Comment: Specifically, `copywhere = where` does not make a copy of the object.

Comment: Thank you for your responses , so you told me that when i make  var copywhere = where , it's not a new object or new var it s the same original where  , Thank you So much for you explanation .

Comment: Same as with a C or C++ pointer--it just references the same thing.

Comment: @DaveNewton thank you so much , I didn't know that before , i will reviews my code to avoid referencing  , thank you again for you explanation .

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with the object or array in javascript it will referring the same reference no matter whether you are copy array/Object in another variable it will change value for all variable belong from the same reference

Please check below example:

```
// Declaring Array
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,6];

//Trying to copy array into another variable
var arr2 = arr1;
console.log("========================");
//Display Array one
console.log(arr1);
//Adding more value in arra1
arr1.push(10);
arr1.push(11);
console.log("========================");
////Display Array Two
console.log(arr2);
console.log("========================");
```

O/P :

```
========================
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 ]        
======================== 
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 10, 11 ]
========================
```

As you can see in above example we are declaring one array and copy that same array into another array then we have push two array inside **arr1** and we display **arry2** it will display array value which is referring to **arr1**